# Counting number of visits to my website

Tags: statistics

I need help understanding how to count the number of daily/weekly visits to my wordpress website.  I've looked online at a couple of "how to" guides.  I can't find a "Stats" section on my site.  Can you help me to insert this.  I do not have a blog and simply want to know how many viewers "click" on my site and view various pages.

Please help asap!

Sheila

Answer (score 2):

There are many different ways to get some stats regarding your site. One of the most popular solutions is to use Jetpack. Check this link for more info:

http://jetpack.me/support/wordpress-com-stats/

Alternatively you may use a plugin such as this one:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-power-stats/

Another solution is to use a separate application such as AwStats which is usually provided by default on cPanel based Linux servers. Of course you may also integrate Google Analytics on your site. Here is a nice plugin for this purpose:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-analytics-for-wordpress/

Answer (score -1):

If you are not planning to use plugins for that you still have your options and you can search for Awstats [here](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&q=install%20awstats%20on%20web%20server).

For instance this is how it can be on [Ubuntu](http://blogging.dragon.org.uk/installing-awstats-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts/).
The advantage is you don't need to save anything in the database this way and you save also processing cycles. 
The downside is you need to configure Awstats and also you need to make it work from outside on your Apache, Nginx or other web server...

Comment: Like your other answer, this isn't really helpful for this poster - or for most other people who would be searching for answers on this site. Questions on this site naturally have a WP flavour, and in some cases - like is clear with this question - we get some inexperienced users who need some more rudimentary guidance. Pointing to server software isn't helpful in this case.

Comment: @TimMalone, this website is not only for the poster in here. Other may  find this answer helpful. I haven't written anything that is bad. More, this answer is distinct from the original because it doesn't force you to use plugins. You may find interesting, but really big companies don't use plugins for tracking website statistics.